# Is there any Facebook API open , where I can connect to Facebook games from my application in WP7

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

for developing wp7 applications , is any API that can be used for calling facebook games.
I want to conenct to a specific facebook game like bubble shooter , where i can connect and play that game in my application

Answer (score 0):

there is a facebook API if you go to the facebook site and look on there.

your question is a little vague though, is it that you want to be able to conenct to a specific facebook game with your app, or do you want your app to be hosted on facebook?

Comment: I want conenct to a specific facebook game like bubble shooter ,from my application and can play the game from my application.